# Is it possible in C# to start an iterator at a specific index?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have an arrow of `string`s

```
string [] cargs
```

and I want to iterate over it beginning at the `k`th index. Is there an alternative to

```
 var iter = cargs.GetEnumerator();
 for (int i = 0; i <= k; ++i) iter.MoveNext();
```

???

Additionally, I'm trying to figure out what type `iter` is in the above snippet of code. When I hover over it in Visual Studio, I'm told that is of type `System.Collections.IEnumerator`, but I change the line to

```
IEnumerator iter = cargs.GetEnumerator();
```

VS tells me `Using the generic System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T> requires 1 type arguments`. I've then tried

```
IEnumerator<string> iter = cargs.GetEnumerator();
```

and

```
IEnumerator<string[]> iter = cargs.GetEnumerator();
```

So ... What type is `cargs.GetEnumerator()`, really?

Comment: Also, click on the `GetEnumerator` code and press F12, it will jump to `System.Collections.IEnumerator`

Comment: The short answer is "no". The `IEnumerator`/`IEnumerator<T>` interface does not provide a method to skip values. You must use something like `.Skip(5)` to provide the illusion that you are skipping values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't iterate manually unless you're writing a custom enumeration method that would benefit from being implemented using manual iteration.

Prefer [`foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) or existing enumeration methods (like [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)) instead.

---

You can start at any index by using the [`Skip(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method on the array (or any other `IEnumerable<T>`, although in some sequences the term *index* isn't applicable).

---

Every [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) has a `GetEnumerator()` method that returns an [`IEnumerator<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx).

However, every `IEnumerable<T>` is also a (non-generic) [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), which has a `GetEnumerator()` method that returns a (non-generic) [`IEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx).

Prefer the generic interface, as the non-generic one is mostly legacy (from the early versions when the type system did not support generic types).

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI

```
//This starts at 0
var k = 31;
var startAT = 0;
for (int i= startAT; i<= k; ++i) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

-------------------------------

//here the start position is changed, you can change to what you like!
//this starts at 30 instead of 0
var k = 31;
var startAT = 30;
for (int i= startAT; i<= k; ++i) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```